# Visual Studio extension: how to get value of $ macro?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I'm writing an extension for Visual Studio 2019 and I need to resolve the values of solution/project macros, e.g. `$(ProjectDir)` and `$(SolutionDir)`. Is there any way to do this from an extension?

Comment: You cannot use `$(ProjectDir)` and `$(SolutionDir)` to get their values in vsix projects while it can be realized by MSBuild tool. To get their values, you can use [DTE Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.dte?view=visualstudiosdk-2017&viewFallbackFrom=visualstudiosdk-2019).

Answer (score 0):

> I need to resolve the values of solution/project macros, e.g.
>   $(ProjectDir) and $(SolutionDir). Is there any way to do this from an
>   extension?

As far as I know, `ProjectDir` and `SolutionDir` are just [MSBuild properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-properties?view=vs-2019) and if you want to use `$()` to get the values of `ProjectDir` and `SolutionDir`, they can ony be recognized by **MSBuild tool** rather than **vsix api**. Using `$` to get properties values can only be used in MSBuild.

To get the values of `$(ProjectDir)` and `$(SolutionDir)` directly, l suggest you can just use [EnvDTE interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.dte?view=visualstudiosdk-2017&viewFallbackFrom=visualstudiosdk-2019) to get the values and it can also be used in VS2019.

**Solution**

**1)** try to reference `EnvDTE.dll` which exists in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\xxxx(Community/Professional/Enterprise)\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies`.

**2)** using namespace `using EnvDTE`;

**3)** add these code in the project which will obtain the values directly.

```
 DTE dTE = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(DTE)) as DTE;
 string solutiondir = dTE.Solution.FileName;  // the value of $(SolutionDir)
 Project project = dTE.Solution.Projects.Item(1);
 string projectdir = project.FileName; // the value of $(projectdir)
```

The result is equal to the values of $(ProjectDir) and $(SolutionDir) in msbuild.

Comment: That's the workaround I came up with too, only I used `dTE.Solution.FindProjectItem(workingFile).ContainingProject.FileName` for the project file. And you forgot to use `Path.GetDirectoryName` on the file names.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder and patient guidance. To get the values, you can directly try this solution which is easier to get  them. Besides, I just have found [IVsBuildPropertyStorage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsbuildpropertystorage?view=visualstudiosdk-2019) and which you could try it.